# Looking for specific alga and a recently extinct (or rare) marine animal from the same region for novel

Tags: limnology, algae

I'm writing a novel where there is a drowned body in an inland lake. The idea is that she was drowned after a fight in a container containing sea water for smuggling a recently extinct (in the novel, supposedly extinct) or a rare marine animal, and there was also some species of alga in her lungs.
Hence, I'm looking for two species from the same ocean or sea (endemic or not), where some info on the genome is known. The best thing (or you tell me if it makes sense at all) I could come up with so far is the Great Auk (Pinguinus impennis) and brown alga of some species which I think is mostly found in the North Atlantic.
Very grateful for any info on the genome (no details necessary, just whether the DNA has been sequenced and whether it would be possibly to identify by a tissue sample), chromosome number and other info on the great auk and some Phaeophyceae alga or any other input for a fitting pair of species. My novel is set in 1994, and they identify the species by forensic PCR methods, no need for a specific match, but by a shred of skin or so I need two marine species identified (not with 100% certainty, good odds or a near-match is enough) by some forensic way, can be anything really, one of them small enough to be in the water in the lungs of a drowned body. Or a genus could be enough, the plot element is just that she drowned in a container used to transport an animal.
Sorry if it's inappropriate to ask this here, it's not a scientific question I know, but I trust I get the highest quality input here.

Actually, the alga is of secondary priority, if someone could point out a recently extinct marine animal which can be matched by its DNA, or by a tissue sample using some other method, I can even scratch the alga, but it would be a nice cherry on top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at least some of the genome has been sequenced for the Great Auk (*Pinguinis impennis)*: [Taxonomy browser @ NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/taxonomy/94623/) (click on the 45 next to the Genomic Sequences title). There appear to be 45 different genomes published. All of them are mitochondrial genomes, which are relatively easy to reconstruct, as well as super abundant in any tissue. They can be used to identify samples to the species level.

I don't know of any specific algae that might match, as these tend to be very widespread (as one might expect for a marine species that is distributed by currents). You might be able to concoct one fresh-water one that comes from some remote island where the Auks are found. Perhaps a land-bound plant pollen or spore (moss, fern) in the lungs instead if she has been collecting these animals from somewhere? It doesn't have to be real after all, just believable (for example Dan Brown's Da Vinci Code theories etc.)!

Comment: You might find this Telegraph book review fun (best book review I ever read): [Don’t make fun of renowned Dan Brown](https://onehundredpages.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/dont-make-fun-of-renowned-dan-brown/).

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think I have seen that before, or perhaps a similar one about another author, still gets a laugh out of me.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the input! I guess the Auk will do then with your confirmation that it can be positively identified by the mDNA -- But, @anongoodnurse, just asking out of curiosity (and thanks for the funny review, or whatever it is, I assume I'm missing out on something, his constantly referring to himself as renowned I assume); is it that (a) this part of the plot sounds so far-out it reminds you of Dan Brown or (b) my grammar or style reminds you of Dan Brown or (c), heaven forbid, both?

Comment: It will be much more far-out pulp stuff than Dan Brown, but with a tiny difference: the book won't take itself seriously. Or so I hope. So heaven forbid anybody associate my grammar or style with Dan Brown, that was my point, although I'm writing the first version in German, so I'm off the hook for the time being.

Comment: @bob1, however, has this been sequenced in 1994? I understand PCR was fairly new then so you'd need a huge sample? Could they run as many cycles as they do today? Also, the genome is only 16k base pairs and 10k are identical, is that correct?
Sounds like nothing, I thought humans have several billions and the onion (I heard) has much more...? But most of it is junk anyway, or so they claim?

Comment: @FissionChips PCR is largely unchanged since the 90's, besides some advances in detection technology, mechanization and enzymes, the reaction used today is the same as Kary Mullis invented. I was doing PCR in the late 90's on machines that are still sold today. Sequencing - massive advances since the 90's. Sanger sequencing (chain termination) is still common and largely unchanged since the 90's too. Both definitely possible and quite sensitive even back then. Wouldn't have been able to do sequences off historical things back then though, ancient DNA tech has come a long way.... cont

Comment: cont... Those are mitochondrial genomes (~16k bases) and all from the same species, so about right in terms of diversity. These will be distinct from other species though, at least in the right regions, so is very useful for species ID. These were [4 mtDNA genomes generated in 1994](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4812591/) -see fig 2 and section "early mtDNA discoveries" for more info. Earliest were 1980's, so it isn't out of the realms of possibility to have had great auk there, it's jsut that people focussed on easy (abundant) species first.

Comment: @FissionChips I mentioned Dan Brown as an e.g. of someone who gets the details wrong, but still tells a story that is believable. Your has to stretch the tech and knowledge a bit to get Great Auk sequenced in the 90's; the ability was almost there, just people hadn't got around to it. Another e.g.: I remember reading a fiction novel in early 2000's about a person with dwarfism who modified an embryo and implanted it in a woman so that the child would carry his form of dwarfism. We weren't capable of doing that sort of thing at the time of setting, but still an interesting read.

Comment: @FissionChips - No, not at all! Actually I upvoted your question because that sounded like a fun twist. I only posted that review because Dan Brown was mentioned and it's so on-point about his writing, which is *terrible*. I doubt he could have written the question you wrote as well as you did. :) He has his fans, though, which is fine by me. I'm not high-falutin (sp?), though. I read The Silmarillion, but actually had to take notes to keep things straight. Could not finish Foundation, though I love Asimov. Too complicated for me.